# Joomla 2.5 - sources of homepage content

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Total Joomla newbie here. I've been asked to help with a site I didn't create, and I don't know Joomla. The site is using Joomla 2.5.

The homepage contains three featured articles, but some additional content is showing up below the third article, above the footer. The admin tool only shows three featured articles, and when I examine the source of the third article, there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with it.

Where can this additional content be coming from? Any suggestions on how to track down how it is getting added to the page?

TIA!

Comment: It could be one of the installed plugins/add-ons

Comment: If you have Firefox you can install the addon called Firebug and then right click on the page and select, Inspect this element with Firebug. You can find out quite a lot this way. You can also do the same thing in Google Chrome although I prefer Firebug myself.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a module - check out the installed modules.

Answer (score 0):

Check the active template, then go to the template folder > your template > index.php. this is the PHP of your site.
Here you can see what modules positions you have, and then check in the admin system > module manager what position is actually in use.